# Android Application Build with MobileFirst 7.1 is Rejected by Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, ibm-mobilefirst

I have An Application developed using Mobile First 7.1. I Added Android Environment and build the Project. I created signed APK from generated Android Project and Uploaded the Google play store and My Application has rejected by Google Play store with below message

> Hello Google Play Developer,
>         We rejected SampleApp, with package name com.Sample.app, for violating our Malicious Behavior or User Data policy. If you submitted
>   an update, the previous version of your app is still available on
>   Google Play. This app uses software that contains security
>   vulnerabilities for users or allows the collection of user data
>   without proper disclosure. Below is the list of issues and the
>   corresponding APK versions that were detected in your recent
>   submission. Please upgrade your app(s) as soon as possible and
>   increment the version number of the upgraded APK. Vulnerability   APK
>   Version(s) Apache Cordova  The vulnerabilities were fixed in Apache
>   Cordova v.4.1.1 or higher. You can find information about how to
>   upgrade in this Google Help Center article. 44 To confirm you’ve
>   upgraded correctly, submit the updated version of your app to the
>   Developer Console and check back after five hours to make sure the
>   warning is gone. While these vulnerabilities may not affect every app
>   that uses this software, it’s best to stay up to date on all security
>   patches. Make sure to update any libraries in your app that have known
>   security issues, even if you're not sure the issues are relevant to
>   your app. Apps must also comply with the Developer Distribution
>   Agreement and Developer Program Policies. If you feel we have made
>   this determination in error, please reach out to our developer support
>   team.

Comment: Errr do we look like Google support?

Comment: Cordova 3.6.4 comes with Mobile first 7.1. How can we upgrade it to 4.1.1 or higher

Comment: `The vulnerabilities were fixed in Apache Cordova v.4.1.1 or higher` is the answer.

Comment: How to upgrade cordova for Mobilefirst 7.1 which comes as inbuilt with product?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't upgrade the Cordova that comes with MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1.  But, the vulnerabilities that Google is concerned about are addressed in the version of Cordova that's shipped with builds of 7.1 published since those fixes were applied, and Google understands how to recognize a MFP app that has the appropriate fixes applied.  So if you apply the most recent iFix for MFP 7.1 and rebuild your app with that, it shouldn't be rejected for that reason.

If you are an IBM customer, the most recent iFix for 7.1 can be obtained [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/quickorder?parent=ibm%7EOther%20software&product=ibm/Other%20software/IBM%20MobileFirst%20Platform%20Foundation&release=7.1.0.0&platform=All&function=fixId&fixids=7.1.0.0-MFPF-IF201703300917&includeRequisites=1&includeSupersedes=0&downloadMethod=http&source=fc).  The fix for this issue is in the Studio component - or CLI, if you build your app that way.  If you are using Studio, you apply the fix by adding the Studio ZIP file that you downloaded (which is an Eclipse p2 installation repository) as a software installation source in Eclipse, and updating.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Please advice latest iFix and provide steps to update.

Answer (score 1):

What is the build level of MobileFIrst 7.1 you're using ? 
The latest build of MobileFirst 7.1 should have this issue fixed.

Comment: I am using   IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.1.0.00-20151227-1725 Please advice which fix of MFP studios i have to use and provide the procedure if possible

Comment: This is very old. You should install the latest iFix , upgrade your environment, rebuild and then deploy to Playstore