# I am having vulnerability issue from google play console while deploying my build regarding apache cordova version 4.1.1 or higher

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, html-framework-7, mobilefirst-server

I am using MOBILE FIRST DEVELOPMENT SERVER. so running **cordova platform android** and other **cordova commands** not working it is showing "**you are not in cordova project**".

Then I found out this solution [Android Application Build with MobileFirst 7.1 is Rejected by Google Play Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43511153/android-application-build-with-mobilefirst-7-1-is-rejected-by-google-play-store?rq=1)

After updating the ifix got the below message from google playStore.

**Thanks for contacting Google Play Developer Support. I understand you have some questions about the Apache Cordova security vulnerability.
I see that version XXX of your app is currently using the following vulnerable implementation of Apache Cordova:
org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer$3
You'll need to upgrade your app to use Apache Cordova v.4.1.1 or higher. New apps or updates containing older versions of Apache Cordova will be blocked.**

Still not able to solve the issue. stucked.....:(
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the version of your MobileFirst installation ? Please add this detail to the question

Comment: You are using MobileFirst development server and you are talking of uploading to Playstore. And what is the specific build level of your client SDK? Did the Google notice talk of a specific vulnerability?

Comment: @VivinK I got the above message from google play I dont have more detail about it.They are having issues with apache cordova version which is less in my project need to upgrade it but not able to understand how to upgrade

Comment: @Srik I am using MFP7.1.0 .00-20170330-0917 Studio this  iFix I am using right now. Please advise which iFix to use

Comment: @VivinK my target SDK is 26

Comment: The version of MFP you're using is more than 2 years old. You should update your MobileFirst Studio to the latest version and then resubmit your app to the Play Store.

Comment: Also, after the iFix upgrade to your MFP studio, ensure you remove and re-add your Android environment for good measure.

Comment: I have updated my MFP studio version to 7.1.0.00.20190329-1256 and still google paly store giving the same vulnerability issue.@Srik

Comment: @VivinK I don't know how to re-add android environment as I am totally new to this whole IBM Mobile First Development thing

Comment: Open application-descriptor.xml in UI mode. You will seen an option to remove Android environment. Once you remove, add it back again. Once that is done, from that project create the apk

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked but now playstore is giving another error regarding 64-bit code.. do you know how to solve this.....Coz I have done the changes that is given in  documentation but it is not generating 64-bit apk only 32 bit apk is generated ...